# Understanding radio button with rails helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select only one button of a two. But right now the functionality of the radio buttons is broken because I can select both on the form and I can't unselect them. Which leads me to believe the form thinks they are for separate objects. Here is what I'm working with:

## Form:

```
 <%= form_for [@event, @invitation_permission] do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :email, value: params[:email] %>
  <%= f.radio_button :event_id, @event.id %> This Event <%= @event.name %>
  <%= f.radio_button :user_id, @event.user.id %> This Organizer <%= @event.user.full_name %>
  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

SO, as you can see I'm trying to update the invitation_permissions table with a new class. Why is it letting me select both radio button. And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have provided 2 different objects to the radio_button, it is tend to consider them different.
Both should be either `:user_id` or `:event_id` to group them into 1.
For radio buttons, they serve as multiple options for single attribute. What you are trying to do seems illogical for radio buttons.
If you still wanna achieve that, you can take help of javascript..